# Inserting an image in a Word document from add-in where the image type is not yet known

Tags: windows, add-in

Inserting an image in a Word document from add-in where the image type is not yet known.    I'm trying to insert an image in a Word document from an Add-in in the Word 2016 client. However, I cannot use the way described here: https://xomino365.com/2016/05/01/inserting-a-base64-encoded-image-into-a-word-2016-document/ using base64 and canvas if I do not know the image type in advance. How do you insert an image in a Word document in and add-in where the image type is not yet known?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could figure out programmatically in JS wat type the image file is and then prepend the right format to the base64 string, an easier way might be to actually use the SetSelectedDataAsync function together with the Office.CoercionType.Html instead. In that way Word will simply insert whatever html is there (presumably an  tag with the appropriate url) and load that.

Hope this helps.

Jesse